# SQL Server DB Connection with Symfony2 and Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, sqlsrv

I'm trying to generate the schema of the database in a SQL Server database, using the following instruction: php app/console doctrine:schema:create.

This is the error message:

Call to undefined function Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\SQLSrv\sqlsrv_connect() in C:\Projects\Project\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\SQLSrvConnection.php

PARAMETERS FILE

```
parameters:
database_driver: pdo_sqlsrv
database_host: localhost
database_port: 1433
database_name: dbname
database_user: user
database_password: password
```

CONFIG FILE

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    driver:   "%database_driver%"
    host:     "%database_host%"
    port:     "%database_port%"
    dbname:   "%database_name%"
    user:     "%database_user%"
    password: "%database_password%"
    #charset:  UTF8
    # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver, add the path in parameters.yml
    # e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
    # path:     "%database_path%"

orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    auto_mapping: true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have NOT installed **php plugin** for that

Comment: Should anyone be too lazy to look for it, there you go for downloading the MSSQL driver: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098